# Which algorithm+representation should I use for finding minimum path distance in a huge sparse undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, data-representation, undirected-graph

I need to find the minimum distance between two nodes in a undirected graph, here are some details

- The graph is **undirected and huge**(no of nodes is in order of 100,000)
- The graph is **sparse**, no of edges is less than no of nodes
- I am **not interested in the actual path**, just the distance.

What representation and algorithm should I use for a) Space efficiency b)time efficiency?

EDIT: If it matters,

- The wieghts are all non zero positive integers.
- No node connects to itself.
- Only single edge between two adjacent nodes

Comment: Well, if the number of edges is less than n-1, just get rid of the disconnected nodes. They don't contribute to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the weights of the edges. If they are non-negative - [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) suits you. If your graph is planar, you can use [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

If you have negative weights, you have to use [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).